# How can I solve the 29 unapplied migration(s) for app(s): admin, api, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions, social_django

Tags: python, django, doccano

I was setting up Doccano on my desktop to perform sequence labeling tasks. I followed the instructions from a website on how to setup Doccano. Everything was working fine until I got to the last code below where I experienced migration errors.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/chakki-works/doccano.git
$ cd doccano
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ cd app
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

This is the error below after running the last code above on git bash

```
You have 29 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, api, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions, social_django.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\okekec\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\okekec\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

File "C:\Users\okekec\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\okekec\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\okekec\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

The error says to Run 'python manage.py migrate. When I ran the code in my terminal I got an [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Please see below.
Thanks for your help.

```
C:\Users\okekec>python manage.py migrate
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: @ AzyCrw4282 Yes, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the folder where manage.py is and run the command there.

`cd /okekec/doccano/app`

`ls`

It should be able to see manage.py file.

Then
`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a Django project, so you are required to manually migrate the required models for the 29 apps that it's referring to.

It seems to me as though you are running this outside the directory that you've cloned

> C:\Users\okekec>

should be

> C:\Users\okekec\doccano>

There, it should have the `manage.py` file, i.e. the file should be in the current directory. This should then allow you to perform the migrations.

Comment: Thank you for your help